# Android - Navigation_Mode_List on ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I did a list navigation with this mode ActionBar.Navigation_Mode_list, but I don't want that appear the first option (or the choosed one) on the menu, I just want appear just the arrow. It's possible that?

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.locations, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
    list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's possible to do so by creating your custom adapter and overriding `getView` method the following way:

```
@Override    
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView title = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    title.setText("");
    return title;
}
```

This will show only the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry -- as with a regular `Spinner`, there is *always* a selection. You are welcome to make the first element in your array be something that renders empty (e.g., an empty string), but then the user will always see that in the drop-down and can always switch back to the "empty" entry.